# How can I check the size of a document in firestore is?

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Because that a document in firestore has a limit of 1MiB i want to look through my document to check how big they are. Is there a simple way to find out the size of a document?

Comment: I think that this [Firestore Document Size Extension](https://extensions.dev/extensions/alexmamo/firestore-document-size) will help.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size) has explained sizes of each data type and description of how storage size is calculated so you can actually calculate it yourself by writing a function. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a package for Dart to do so. There is a npm package called [firestore-size](https://github.com/alekslario/firestore-size/blob/master/lib/sizeof.js) which might be helpful to write the same function in Dart.

Essentially you just need to loop over all the fields in the document and keep on adding their individual size for example, if the value is `hello` add 6 as the documentation says for a string the size will be 'Number of UTF-8 encoded bytes + 1', for a null add 1 and so on..

Answer (score 0):

So you want to check the size of file on the phone:

The function:

```
getFileSize(String filepath, int decimals) async {
    var file = File(filepath);
    int bytes = await file.length();
    if (bytes <= 0) return "0 B";
    const suffixes = ["B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB"];
    var i = (log(bytes) / log(1024)).floor();
    return ((bytes / pow(1024, i)).toStringAsFixed(decimals)) + ' ' + suffixes[i];  
}
```

How to use it:

```
print(getFileSize('file-path-will-be-here', 1));
```

What is the result:

```
97.5 KB
```